# Mathematical proof of mapping between 2 spaces

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have 2 spaces. The first space is $s_1=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, the second space is the positive real numbers up to $N$. Both spaces are related to the preference degree of some users, the higher the number, the stronger the preference.

How can I proof mathematically that a function that maps between these two sets always exists? Is there such a proof?

Comment: This is not clear. Of course there are functions between these...as there are between any two sets.  Presumably you want those functions to have special properties.  What properties did you want?

Comment: `Of course there are functions between these...as there are between any two sets.` is there a mathematical proof that ensures that at least that function exists? How can I know for sure? intuitively, it looks there exists, but I don't know if there is a proof for that. In terms of the properties, my knowledge about spaces is limited. Ideally, I would like to find the map between these two spaces, we are looking at conditional probability + Kernel density estimation or calibration. But first we would like to make sure that the function exists

Comment: @MiguelGonzalez-Fierro Of course at least one function exists. For example, the function that maps everything to 0.

Comment: ok thanks @JackM

Comment: I'm sure you have some properties in mind.  I doubt, for example, that constant functions help you here.  What properties were you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given two non-empty sets $A$ and $B$, there is always a function from $A$ to $B$, since we can pick some element $b$ out of $B$ and map every element of $A$ to $b$. If you want to get super philosophical, we can probably start talking about set theory axioms, but there's not much point other than just for the sake of it.